# Negative values when absolutely positioning monitor in xorg.conf

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, xorg

In xorg.conf, in the ServerLayout section, I'm trying to arrange screens 0 and 1. Screen 1 's left top corner should be up 1050 pixels and right 880 pixels. But negative values seem to be causing an error:

```
Screen 0 "Screen0" Absolute 0 0
Screen 1 "Screen1" Absolute 880 -1050
```

How do I accomplish this?

```
      B----------------+----------------+
      |                |                |
      |                |                |        This is X Screen 1
      |                |                |        Two 1680x1050 screens
      |                |                |
A-----+----------------+----------------+-----+
|                      |                      |
|                      |                      |
|                      |                      |  This is X Screen 0
|                      |                      |  Two 2560x1440 screens
|                      |                      |
|                      |                      |
+----------------------+----------------------+
```

As you can see, Point B should be up 1050 and to the right 880 of point A.

Comment: I believe that you are confused. The top left is (0,0) but as you go down  the numbers get positive. Even if the above is not strictly correct, there is no way to get negative values. Try flipping it to positive.

Comment: @soandos What do you mean by "flipping it positive"? Flip what?

Comment: Change -1050 to 1050

Comment: @soandos I did that and X now thinks Screen1 is below Screen0.

Comment: So swap the values for screen 0 and screen 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the thing I was getting confused about: I was defining Point B's position in relation to Point A, but I should have been defining both of their positions in relation to Point C:

```
C     B----------------+----------------+
      |                |                |
      |                |                |        This is X Screen 1
      |                |                |        Two 1680x1050 screens
      |                |                |
A-----+----------------+----------------+-----+
|                      |                      |
|                      |                      |
|                      |                      |  This is X Screen 0
|                      |                      |  Two 2560x1440 screens
|                      |                      |
|                      |                      |
+----------------------+----------------------+
```

This is the correct config.

```
Screen 0 "Screen0" Absolute 0 1050
Screen 1 "Screen1" Absolute 880 0
```

Thanks, soandos for leading me in the correct direction.

Comment: This is not correct...

Comment: Working fine for me. Can you please be more specific?